# DLNA servers among 2 home networks

Tags: router, dlna

I have 2 networks, each one with its own internet connection, ISP modem-router , a dlna server(running [serviio](https://serviio.org/)), some clients and the goal is to connect these two networks.

From each network, there is **only** one Ethernet cable available to the other network,
so what I have done so far is to configure static routes on both ISP's router and put a third router to achieve routing between the two networks. The router is temporarily a Airlive N.Power.

After this, I can successfully ping and access files on the other network. So far so good. Unfortunately, the dlna servers are not discoverable in the other network.

To better explain it, assuming that we have a TV as dlna client in network A, this TV only discovers the dlna server of its own network and not the one at network B.

Serviio uses [TCP port 8895 and UDP 1900](https://www.serviio.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=21#q1).I guess that I have to forward traffic at these ports among networks but I am not aware where should I apply this. On ISP routers, on third router or both?

**Question**: How I can make dlna servers to be automatically discovered in the other network?

Comment: DLNA conceptually uses multicast, so you need multicast routing both on your connecting router and on the two ISP routers. This is not trivial to set up, and even if you know how to, lots of things can still go wrong, from your appliances using broadcast instead of multicast to [more subtle issues](https://www.garyhawkins.me.uk/dlna-upnp-and-multicast-routing/). So don't expect a step-by-step recipe. A simpler solution may be to hook up a single DLNA server to both networks (using a tunnel/VLAN if necessary), if bandwidth permits this.

Answer (score 2):

As @dirkt stated in the comments, my requirement is not an easy one. But I managed to find a solution.

At first, I replaced the third router standing between two networks with `pfsense` installed on an old pc.

`pfsense` comes with [IGMP proxy](https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/book/services/igmp-proxy.html) for managing multicast routing. Enabling it didn't work for me.

So I searched for other multicast routing solutions and I found [pimpd](https://github.com/troglobit/pimd).

I installed it manually to `pfsense` as it is not included in official packages, and started the server using default configuration file and voila, DLNA servers are discovered, with a delay I have to admit. This may be improved by messing with the configuration.

**Note:** I would not accept my answer, hoping for a better one.

Answer (score 0):

Try smcroute.

Config File:

```
mgroup from br-lan group 239.255.255.250
mroute from br-lan group 239.255.255.250 source 192.168.9.220 to br-WAN
```

Where "br-lan" is your local network device and "br-WAN" the destination. "192.168.9.220" is the IP of the DLNA server of your local network. This config is unidirectional.

Firewall rule to increase Multicast TTL +1:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i br-lan -d 239.255.255.250 -j TTL --ttl-inc 1
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).